# Why am I getting this error posting a request to the Uber Sandbox? NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I can get product ID's from the products path but I get this error when trying to post a request to the sandbox schedule a ride. Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have the bearer token added. I'm not sure what it wants or what is missing.

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7f8c13939ed0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8c0ac78410 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests}`

```
func performPostUberRequest(url: NSURL, prodId: String) {
    let params:[String: AnyObject] = [
        "start_latitude" : "39.955715",
        "start_longitude" : "-75.1680298",
        "end_latitude" : "39.9542675",
        "end_longitude" : "-75.1409609",
        "product_id": prodId
    ]

    var error: NSError?
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(uberToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        response, data, error in
        if let error = error {
            println(error)
        } else if data != nil {
            if let json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
                println(json)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the http code returned to you?

Comment: That's a good question, how can I get that info? I'm trying to figure out how to see the entire raw request/response.

Comment: I also found more info in "data", but response was nil. {
    code = unauthorized;
    message = "Missing scope: request";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments: `{ code = unauthorized; message = "Missing scope: request"; }`, you may miss the scope, which can be specified on your Uber developer dashboard where you registered the app and got the secret and client id and stuff.

If you have done this you should have added the necessary scopes into the parameters when you requested `authorization code` and `access token` through `OAuth2.0` at the beginning.

In my imeplementation, the scopes were specified as the following:

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] setClientID:_clientID
                                         secret:_clientSecret
                                          scope:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"request", @"history_lite", @"profile", @"request_receipt", nil]
                               authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize"]
                                       tokenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://login.uber.com/oauth/token"]
                                    redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_redirectURL]
                                  keyChainGroup:nil
                                 forAccountType:_applicationName];
```

Comment: Your answer was in Objective C but the main fix wasn't anymore than adding a string called "request" to the dictionary under the string "scope". Thanks.